# jQuery for each value in a cookie

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, each

I've got a cookie and I need to pull it's values and run a function on each of them. Not sure about how to separate the values... so here's what I'm working with:

```
var cookie = [1,2,3],
    val = cookie.methodThatSplitsEachValueIntoASeparateObject;

val.each(function(){
    //I'm running on 1, 2, and 3!
});
```

Comment: cookies have to be string... have you already created array from string?

Comment: Yessir. @VisioN has the correct method, just have to work out a detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
    var val = cookie[i];
    // alert(val);
}
```

jQuery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$.each(cookie, function(i, val) {
    // alert(val);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It's Sunday. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Ah! ran into one thing. The variable val is the index of the value, but i want the value itself. Simple way? http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/gbTxc/1/

Comment: @technopeasant Use `function(i, val)`, as in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/gbTxc/2/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you iterate through the array?

```
for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++) {
//Create object from cookies[i]
}
```

Hope that helps.